# How do I dynamically filter fields returned in django rest api get request based on the user making the request?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have a photoshoot api that allows photographers to post shoot photos from which `preview` and `watermarded` versions are derived. Editors and clients can both select which photos will be edited, but the editor should only see the `preview` without watermark and the clients should only see the `watermarked` versions.
I was wondering how these different distincitons can be made in the DRF queryset.
My model:

```py
class Unedited(models.Model):
    shoot = models.ForeignKey(
        Shoot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="shoot_photo"
    )
    original = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to=shoot_upload_to)
    preview = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=shoot_upload_to)
    watermarked = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=shoot_upload_to)
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Serializer:

```py
class UneditedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Unedited
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["preview"] = reduce_resolution(validated_data["original"])
        validated_data["watermarked"] = add_watermark(validated_data["preview"])
        img_obj = Unedited.objects.create(**validated_data)
        img_obj.save()
        return img_obj
```

My view:

```py
class UneditedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    if not TESTING:
        permission_classes = (PhotosPermission,)
    serializer_class = UneditedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Unedited.objects.filter(**self.request.query_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by creating separate serializers with different `fields` for the different cases.
`UneditedSerializer` remained as is but I created other serializers:

```py
class UneditedMarkedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Unedited
        fields = ("watermarked", "shoot", "upload_time")


class UneditedPreviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Unedited
        fields = ("preview", "shoot", "upload_time")
```

I then modified the viewset to check against the user making the request to determine which serializer to use. Like so:

```py
class UneditedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    if not TESTING:
        permission_classes = (PhotosPermission,)
    serializer_class = UneditedSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return generic_queryset(Unedited, self.request.query_params)

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if request.user.is_anonymous or request.user.role == "CLIENT":
            serializer = UneditedMarkedSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        elif request.user.role == "EDITOR":
            print(request.user.role)
            serializer = UneditedPreviewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        elif request.user.role in ("ADMIN", "STAFF"):
            serializer = UneditedSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And now it works as intended.